# Add section to recycle View in run time with dynamic array

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am trying to add section/header in recycle View
 as we have to handle section stuff in

```
@Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
// here your custom logic to choose the view type
return position == 0 ? section: item;
```

}

but i am having arraylist which have n number of data . so say 1st section may have 10 row where as 2nd may have 2 row .so how to define section in this case .where i come to know this is the end of 1st section ? and put 2nd one

Comment: you could use any library, for example [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each model and remember the previous section name of each model item. When ever you find a new section name, just map the index.

In your adapter return items count that is fewer than data set.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount(){
   return mData.size() + mSections.size();
}
```

Always use `position + 1`, because you are always one position ahead.

Whenever you reach for position that belongs to the mapped indexes, return section type and bind it accordingly:

```
@Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
// here your custom logic to choose the view type
  return isPositionSectionIndex(position) ? VIEW_TYPE_SECTION: VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
}
```